# How can I select objects by list size in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

My entity is defined like this:

```
public class Entity implements Serializeable {
      @ManyToMany(mappedBy="entities")
      private List<OtherEntity> otherEntities;

}
```

How can I select in HQL all Entities which have more than one OtherEntity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this should work. This will generate a SQL with a subquery - not fetch it and filter it in memory.

```
from Entity e where e.otherEntities.size > 1
```